# How to force uninstall webpart from Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm trying to delete a webpart in Sharepoint Server 2010 going at

administration->system settings->manage farm solutions..

And the Webpart shows this message "Deployment Status:  Error"

I'm trying "retract solution" and seems work, but when I'm trying to re-deploy the webpart I get the message "Error in the implementation step 'Add Solution': Already installed a feature with ID XXX-XXX - XXX in this set of servers. Use the force attribute to re-add the feature explicitly."

How can I absolute delete this webpart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to force uninstall the feature. Here is the command you can run from stsadm.

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id "yourGUID" -force
```

Once this is done you can redeploy your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing some terminologies here. In the central administration you only have solutions (i.e. WSP files). Inside this solution you might have a webpart or anything else you want to deploy.

You now state that the solution you want to deploy has the status "deployment error" and you **are** able to retract the solution.

What you didn't state: After retracting the solution, did you delete it? This needs to be done! Try to delete the solution after retracting, then upload it again and try to deploy again.

If you want to force a deletion there are several possibilities, e.g. using [Powershell](http://www.sharepointpromag.com/article/sharepoint/managing-solution-packages-using-powershell) or [stsadm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261929%28office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the error message that I get is when I'm trying to retract the solution. So I can't delete because I can't retract before.

Comment: Your question states otherwise, you stated that when re-deploying you get an error. Check the ULS logs on why the retract is actually failing and post your result.